# RPC communication using XDR language between two hosts

Tags: rpc, xdr

How does XDR language ensure that communication between two hosts (same or different architecture/instruction set) is independent of endianness and instruction set of hosts?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol has its own endianness on the wire which all hosts must respect.  Hosts without matching native endianness have to flip the byte order of values they transmit and receive.

The instruction set should not matter, as message formatting, parsing and transport code is generated and compiled distinctly for both client and server.  As with so many network protocols.